# Sending data from Django to Unity using Websocket-Sharp

Tags: django, unity-game-engine, websocket-sharp

I want to send data via Websocket from my django server to my unity game. The websocket connect and disconnects corectly, but i can't send any data to unity.

In django consumers.py I have this:

```
class SensorDataConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("connected")
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("disconnected")
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # Process the received message from Unity if needed
        print("received")
        pass

    async def send_data(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        print("Sending data:", message)
        await self.send(text_data=message)
```

In routing.py I have this:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/sensordata/$', SensorDataConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

I set the asgi like this:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns)
})
```

When the game starts, i connect the websocket. When the method send_sensor_data from views.py is called, i want to send the data to unity. I have this code for the method:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_sensor_data(request):

    sensor_data_consumer = SensorDataConsumer()
    async_to_sync(sensor_data_consumer.send_data({'message': 'Hello, world!'}))

    return Response({'success': True})
```

In Unity, I have a script for websocket:

```
public class SensorDataReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebSocket ws;

    void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.5:8000/ws/sensordata/");
        ws.OnMessage += OnMessageReceived;
        
        ws.Connect();
    }

    void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the received message here
        Debug.Log("Received message: " + e.Data);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (ws != null)
        {
            ws.OnMessage -= OnMessageReceived;
            ws.Close();
            ws = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried a lot of ways to send the data but it does not send anything, only connection and disconnection work.